# CodeIgniter - Setting Checkbox/Radio values from SQL query

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to create an edit page, which brings all of the original values from the database in at first, then let's the form_validation library take over afterwards. I have managed to get everything working as intended but checkboxes and radio buttons.

Here's an example of my form, pretty generic...

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="protocols[]" value="online" <?php echo set_checkbox('protocols[]', 'online');?> /> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="protocols[]" value="network" <?php echo set_checkbox('protocols[]', 'network');?> />
    <input type="checkbox" name="protocols[]" value="splitscreen" <?php echo set_checkbox('protocols[]', 'splitscreen');?> />
```

The database values return as a comma separated string (online,splitscreen).

I also have another 3 field checkbox array to populate, a 9 field checkbox field, and a 3 field radio section to fill.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the brackets from the field name in your call to `set_checkbox()`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="protocols[]" value="online" <?php echo set_checkbox('protocols', 'online');?> /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="protocols[]" value="network" <?php echo set_checkbox('protocols', 'network');?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="protocols[]" value="splitscreen" <?php echo set_checkbox('protocols', 'splitscreen');?> />
```

The form validation library will take care of checking the box or not, but it responds to the `$_POST` array only, so you'll have to use the third parameter to get the inputs checked by default:

> #### set_checkbox()
>
> Permits you to display a checkbox in the state it was submitted. The
>   first parameter must contain the name of the checkbox, the second
>   parameter must contain its value, and the third (optional) parameter
>   lets you set an item as the default (use boolean TRUE/FALSE).

Not a great explanation, but here's an example. First get your values from the comma separated string:

> The database values return as a comma separated string (online,splitscreen).

```
// Something like this
$values = explode(',', $my_data); // Now it's an array
```

Then check if each checkbox's value is in that array:

```
<?php echo set_checkbox(
    'protocols',
    'splitscreen',
    in_array('splitscreen', $values) // TRUE checks the box, FALSE does not
);?>
```

I'd do this in a loop for convenience reasons if nothing else. It's also worth looking at `form_checkbox()` which will make this a good deal easier.

See user guide for details: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: I had no clue that would work, but the in_array() as the third perimeter works exactly like I had wanted. Thank you!